# Mathematical conversion linear input curve to "logarithm-like" output curve in C on limited resources

Tags: math, embedded

I need to make mathematical conversion of input value (linear curve) to output value ("logarithm or exponential-like" curve) on MCU with limited resources (memory, clock speed).

But this question is more general C programming questions.

Let's say, we have two variables: `uint8_t input` and `uint8_t output`. Input values are `0-255`. Output values should be also `0-255`, but changing not linear with input.

For example (input ==> output):

```
    0   ==> 0
    1   ==> 1
    10  ==> 1
    100 ==> 10
    200 ==> 75
    250 ==> 225
    255 ==> 255
```

Let's say, I can do mathematical conversion, something like (in general) " 2^(input/32)-1 " and I can achieve something close to what I need. I tried:

`output = (pow(2, (input/32)))-1`

But, according to limitation of `uint8_t` type variables, I'll get output with powers of 2: 1, 2, 4... up to 128 (minus 1) with no smooth transitions between them:

```
    0   ==> 0
    1   ==> 0
    10  ==> 0
    100 ==> 7
    200 ==> 63
    250 ==> 127
    255 ==> 127
```

Also I prefer not to use `pow()`, because of limited MCU resources.
I can achieve required result with the use of table in memory, but (again) it will cost 256 bytes of ROM, what is not acceptable. Also I can use smaller table and make an approximation, but...

May be there is some other ways to achieve this result in mathematical way, remaining inside `uint8-uint32` arithmetic on low resources MCU?

EDIT: The "correct" formula and numbers doesn't exist. Output numbers could vary. At "input=0" ==> "output=0", at "input=255" ==> "output=255". The requirement: smallest and fastest compiled code. The expected result should be close to this graph (in uint8_t): [image: graph]

Comment: In the pow variant you can divide by 32.0 to avoid the "stepping" issue (so it's a float division instead of an integer one).

Comment: Can't you put your pre-calculated table in flash memory?

Comment: @FelixPalme Ok, I wrote RAM, but really ROM (Flash), my mistake, but I have only 1 K of Flash on ATtiny13A. :) This doesn't really matter, RAM or ROM in this case.

Comment: @PaulStelian Thanks for suggestion. This can do the trick, but will see for other options for now.

Comment: "up to 128 (minus 1)" - why not 128? Anyway, this is a mathematical problem, not a specific programming thing.

Comment: @cyclone125 Could you please add to your question a table of 256 values showing the actual output you want from this function? As it stands, your question is a bit unclear — for example, you want the function to output `1` for an input of `1`, but then say it should obey the formula `output = (pow(2, (input/32)))-1`. These are incompatible requirements, even if you use floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, I don't understand exactly, what do you mean: "why not 128?" Because "pow(2, (input/32))" gives me 128, and then there is "-1" at the end, and I got "127". I have to subtract one to get "0" output at "0" input. I think, this is "programming thing", because I can get the result in mathematical way, but not by program in described circumstances (at least, I don't know how, may be you do).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Yes, you are right. This is because I write this numbers as an example. I tried several formulas for calculation. The "correct" formula and numbers doesn't exist. Output numbers could vary. The expected result should be close to this graph (in uint8_t): http://imgur.com/a/wLeD0

Comment: @Olaf the tags [tag:c] and [tag:avr-gcc] give important scope conditions on the *possible* solutions, I don't think you should remove these.

Comment: Best thing to do is to use a ROM stored correction curve and interpolate between values of correction table.

Comment: @cyclone125: `uint8_t` as you mention has an range of **exactly `0..255` guaranteed**. If you get `-1`, there is s bug in your code, but not related to `uint8_t`! The effect you mention **could** happen if you use signed integers and overflow. As that is undefined behaviour, your code would be no valid C program! With the information given, your statement does not make sense!

Comment: @FelixPalmen: We are not a coding service. The question as-is is purely programming or maths. Restrictions about the allowed values and operations is not a specific matter to the C language. Once he has the algorithm right, OP should be able to translate it to C. Otherwise he might ask another **specific** question about his C problem using the C tag.

Comment: "but..."  but what?  We need to know the constraints and precision required in order to advise.

Comment: @Olaf I think, we didn't understand each other. I wrote, that I didn't understand exactly what you mean. May be my English is not very good. I understand, that `uint8_t` counts only `0..255`. I mean, I should subtract 1 in formula to get 0 output at 0 input (it gave me 1 output at 0 input). That what I mean. Not "-1" as output, but "-1" at the end of the formula. May be my question was not so clear, but I dont know, why you are so worried about my tags. Other people answering here understood what I mean and have helped me, not just deleted my tags and wrote that my question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Clifford But I need more options. Precision is not the most important thing. I am sorry, if my question is not very clear, but sometimes you have not very clear tasks. I tried to described everything what is important as short, as I can. Lookup table and interpolation is the last thing to do, if there is no way to get result other way. I was pretty sure, that there are other ways. The answer is very satisfactory for me. May be there are other, more simple ways, but I don't know about them, that's way I was asking the question. Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: @cyclone125: I don't think the language is the problem here. It seems like you did not understand the problem youself exactly. That's a bad situation to ask here, as we are not a tutoring or discussion forum, but a Q&A site. I'd strongly recommend to think it over **first** what you actually want, do some research on the subject and its adjascent fields where necessary. There are various ways to implement a discrete `log` function. The PIC just adds additional constraints, but these can be figured out in the next stage. Btw. this is basic engineering practice, not specific to this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Let's say, I can do mathematical conversion, something like (in general) " 2^(input/32)-1 " and I can achieve something close to what I need.

You can get an approximation of `2^(input/32)` by using the remainder to do a linear interpolation. Assuming `input` is an integer, you can calculate the equivalent of `(1 + (input%32)/32.0) * pow(2, input/32)` using simple 8-bit calculations:

```
uint8_t f(uint8_t input) {
    uint8_t t = (input & 31) + 32;
    uint8_t u = input >> 5;
    return u < 5 ? t >> (5 - u) : t << (u - 5);
}
```

This will give you a linear interpolation between the powers of two, that looks like this:
[image: Interpolation of powers-of-two]

**Update** (math background)

We want to approximate function `f(input) = pow(2.0, input/32.0)` that requires floating point operations with only integer operations. Obvious approach is to split range `0-255` into sub-ranges of size 32 and use the values at `0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192` which can be calculated using only integers and then do simple [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) for the values in between. Now assume that we want to approximate function value for some `input` such that `32*u <= input < 32*(u+1)` where `u` is an integer. We know the values at the ends: `f(32*u) = 2^u` and `f(32*(u+1)) = 2^(u+1)`. Using linear interpolation we get following approximation:

```
f_approx(input) = [f(32*(u+1))*(input - 32*u) + f(32*u)*(32*(u+1) - input)]/32
```

Now let's simplify it:

```
f_approx(input) = [2^(u+1)*(input - 32*u) + 2^u*(32 - (input - 32*u))]/32
f_approx(input) = 2^u*[2*(input - 32*u) + 32 - (input - 32*u)]/32
f_approx(input) = 2^u*[(input - 32*u) + 32]/2^5
f_approx(input) = [(input - 32*u) + 32]*2^(u-5)
```

Now if we notice that `32` is a power of `2` we can see that `(input - 32*u)` which is the same as `input % 32` can also be calculated as `input & 31`. Thus

```
f_approx(input) = t*2^(u-5)
```

and the ternary if in the `return` just handles the sign of `u-5` to calculate power of 2 using shifts.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! Exactly what I need. Thank you! But still don't understand how did you do this. I mean, I understand each operation, but not a whole algorithm of calculation. May be you can give me some links to read about this topic?

Comment: DKrueger, I took a liberty with updating your answer with "math background" section requested by @cyclone125. Please, feel free to edit it any way you like.

Comment: @cyclone125 : In your question you said _"I can use smaller table and make an approximation, but..."_ but did not elaborate the _"but.."_.  What makes this approximation acceptable, when you had doubts previously?

Comment: @Clifford, I suspect that the reason is that this function is really short and uses only integer math i.e. will not consume a lot of memory or CPU and thus provides a good tradeoff, much better than using an explicit smaller table and explicit interpolation (unless you have some clever tricks of your own in which case you are welcome to show them).

Comment: @SergGr : I agree; it is not a criticism of the answer, but rather that the unstated constraint in the question makes it impossible to tell whether this would be acceptable - it is a criticism of the question. The statement in the question does not make it clear whether what level of precision or memory usage is acceptable or which is more important - it just says "but..".  The comment was intended to encourage the OP to be more explicit.

Comment: @SergGr Thank you for the explanation. I understand what is doing, but for now still not clearly understand how. I will spend more time to dive into this and study. You've been very helpful!

Comment: @SergGr Thanks for the update. I typically struggle with clearly explaining such things myself.

Comment: Great! For my use case, I rounded it off with a "if input == 0 return 0", as I was using it to control lights and the lowest setting should have them completely off.